# ggcorrplot2 shows different significance asterisks

Tags: r, ggcorrplot

does anybody have an idea why ggcorrplot2 shows different significance asterisks than ggcorrplot? Very confusing to me.

[image]

[image]

https://github.com/caijun/ggcorrplot2

```
data(mtcars)
ct <- corr.test(mtcars)
corr <- ct$r
p.mat <- ct$p
ggcorrplot(corr, type= "lower", p.mat = p.mat, 
                 insig = "label_sig", sig.lvl = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001),show.diag=F)
ggcorrplot.mixed(corr, upper = "number", lower = "circle", p.mat = p.mat, 
                 insig = "label_sig", sig.lvl = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001))
```

Update: Ok I think I figured it out finally. Its because `corr.test()` writes a unsymmetric matrix of p.values.
"Entries above the diagonal are adjusted for multiple tests."
I fixed this with `p.mat[lower.tri(p.mat)] <- t(p.mat)[lower.tri(p.mat)]`.
Furthermore if you want to use the adjusted p.Values it is important to mirror the triangle above the diagonal of the p.Value matrix. If you need the unadjusted p.Values it is the lower triangle that needs to be mirrored (code needs to be changed accordingly).

```
data(mtcars)
cor.matrix <- corr.test(mtcars,method = "spearman", adjust = "BH", alpha = 0.05, ci = F)
corr <- cor.matrix[["r"]]
p.mat <- cor.matrix[["p"]]
p.mat[lower.tri(p.mat)] <- t(p.mat)[lower.tri(p.mat)] #to get only the adjusted p.Values symmetrically over the plot

p.mat[lower.tri(p.mat, diag = T)] <- 1 #to set the lower triangle to 1
corrplot.mixed(corr, order= "original",mar=c(0,0,2,0), tl.col = 'black', p.mat = p.mat, insig = "label_sig", sig.level = c(.001, .01, .05), pch.cex=1.5, tl.cex = .8, number.font=2, number.cex=0.8)
```

[image: Final Corrplot]

Comment: Since the package is relatively new/under construction, if it were me, I would fork the package on GitHub and hack the code until it did what I wanted ...

Comment: More suitable as an issue at GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data(mtcars)
cor.matrix <- corr.test(mtcars,method = "spearman", adjust = "BH", alpha = 0.05, ci = F)
corr <- cor.matrix[["r"]]
p.mat <- cor.matrix[["p"]]
p.mat[lower.tri(p.mat)] <- t(p.mat)[lower.tri(p.mat)] #to get only the adjusted p.Values symmetrically over the plot

p.mat[lower.tri(p.mat, diag = T)] <- 1 #to set the lower triangle to 1 (this way the asterisks wont be displayed on this part of the graph)
corrplot.mixed(corr, order= "original",mar=c(0,0,2,0), tl.col = 'black', p.mat = p.mat, insig = "label_sig", sig.level = c(.001, .01, .05), pch.cex=1.5, tl.cex = .8, number.font=2, number.cex=0.8)
```